# Theano: Reconstructing convolutions with stride (subsampling) in an autoencoder

Tags: neural-network, convolution, theano, conv-neural-network

I want to train a simple convolutional auto-encoder using Theano, which has been working great. However, I don't see how one can reverse the `conv2d` command when subsampling (stride) is used. Is there an efficient way to "invert" the convolution command when stride is used, like in the image below?

[image: Image shamelessly stolen and painted from http:/cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks.]

For example, I want to change the following ...

```
from theano.tensor.nnet.conv import conv2d
x = T.tensor4('x') 
y = T.tanh(  conv2d( x, W, border_mode='valid', subsample = (1,1) )  )
z = conv2d( y, Wprime, border_mode='full', subsample = (1,1)  )
```

... into the situation where `subsample = (2,2)`. The first layer will work work just as expected. However, the second layer will effectively "do a convolution with stride 1, then throw away half of the outputs". This is clearly a different operation than what I'm looking for - `z` won't even have the same number of neurons as length as `x`. What should the second `conv2d` command be to "reconstruct" the original `x`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I deduce from this that you intend to have tied weights, i.e. if the first operation were are matrix multiplication with `W`, then the output would be generated with `W.T`, the adjoint matrix. In your case you would thus be looking for the adjoint of the convolution operator followed by subsampling.

(EDIT: I deduced wrongly, you can use any filter whatsoever to 'deconvolve', as long as you get the shapes right. Talking about the adjoint is still informative, though. You will be able to relax the assumption afterwards.)

Since the convolution operator and subsampling operators are linear operator, lets denote them by `C` and `S` respectively and observe that convolution + subsampling an image `x` would be

```
S C x
```

and that the adjoint operation on `y` (which lives in the same space as `S C x`) would be

```
C.T S.T y
```

Now, S.T is nothing other than upsampling to the original image size by adding zeros around all entries of `y` until the right size is obtained.

From your post, you seem to be aware of the adjoint of the convolution operator of stride (1, 1) - it is the convolution with reversed filters and reversed `border_mode`, i.e. with `filters.dimshuffle(1, 0, 2, 3)[:, :, ::-1, ::-1]` and switch from `border_mode='valid'` to `border_mode='full'`.

Concatenate upsampling and this reverse filter convolution and you obtain the adjoint you seek.

Note: There may be ways of exploiting the gradient `T.grad` or `T.jacobian` to obtain this automatically, but I am never sure how this is done exactly.

EDIT: There, I wrote it down :)

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

filters = theano.shared(np.random.randn(4, 3, 6, 5).astype('float32'))

inp1 = T.tensor4(dtype='float32')

subsampled_convolution = T.nnet.conv2d(inp1, filters, border_mode='valid', subsample=(2, 2))

inp2 = T.tensor4(dtype='float32')
shp = inp2.shape
upsample = T.zeros((shp[0], shp[1], shp[2] * 2, shp[3] * 2), dtype=inp2.dtype)
upsample = T.set_subtensor(upsample[:, :, ::2, ::2], inp2)
upsampled_convolution = T.nnet.conv2d(upsample,
     filters.dimshuffle(1, 0, 2, 3)[:, :, ::-1, ::-1], border_mode='full')

f1 = theano.function([inp1], subsampled_convolution)
f2 = theano.function([inp2], upsampled_convolution)

x = np.random.randn(1, 3, 10, 10).astype(np.float32)
f1x = f1(x)
y = np.random.randn(*f1x.shape).astype(np.float32)
f2y = f2(y)

p1 = np.dot(f1x.ravel(), y.ravel())
p2 = np.dot(x.ravel(), f2y[:, :, :-1].ravel())

print p1 - p2
```

`p1` being equal to `p2` corroborates that f2 is the adjoint of f1

Comment: Of course you can skip the `set_subtensor` with all the zeros if you smartly dissect the filter into what it sees at even and odd strides ... (maybe it would be worth it to understand that gradient thing)

Comment: Another note: if you are not out for tied weights and adjointness, you can also use other values than zero in the upsampling (e.g. nearest neighbor).

Comment: Thanks, the zero padding between the hidden neurons is exactly what I was looking for! (Amazing how simple it actually is...). I was hoping that there would be some implementation that would avoid the unnecessary calculation of convolutions (e.g. the ones involving our zero's - I believe these strides are often used to improve speed), so I'll try to look into the grad/jacobian.

Comment: (continued) I believe your code doesn't apply actual subsampling, so for others reading this, I'd like to share these changes (there's no space for full code here):

`subsampled_convolution = T.nnet.conv2d(inp1, filters, border_mode='valid', subsample = (2,2))`

`upsample = T.zeros((shp[0], shp[1], shp[2] * 2, shp[3] * 2)).astype('float32')`


`upsampled_convolution = T.nnet.conv2d(upsample,  `  

`x = np.random.randn(1, 3, 11, 10).astype(np.float32) ## The input must cause the hidden neurons to have a size of an integer times subsample size `

Comment: Thanks for the catch, talk about a way to actually NOT answer a question :) I made the appropriate edits, but do not have to figure out the general idea behind the shape discrepancy that crops up. Concerning your concern about the unnecessary convolutions, either take a look at this mythical gradient thing ;), or divide the problem into 4 different convolutions each with a different filter, acting on the subsampled data and then reconstruct.